# handling button click event in a fragment in xamarin

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android

so i'm creating an android app using Xamarin.android and i'm using the navigation drawer app. I added a fragment and within the fragment I added a button. now I need to handle some events of this button. I tried adding a click event function in the fragment.cs code but I got an exception "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'". how am I supposed to handle the event?
this is the code of my main activity where I access my fragment when choosing the camera icon option:

```
 Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
        public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.ItemId;

            if (id == Resource.Id.nav_camera)
            {
                SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                           .Replace(Resource.Id.mainFrame, fragment )
                           .Commit();
}
```

and this is my fragment's xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="hi"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my fragment's c# code where I try to access the button:

```
 public class Fragment1 : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here

        }


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, container, false);
            Button bulogin = View.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            bulogin.Click += Bulogin_Click;
            // return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            return view;
        }

        private void Bulogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextView txt = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
             txt.Text = "bye";

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the code for us?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT sure sir I've added it

Comment: I test the code you privided. It works well. Based on my test, if the `button1` and `textView1` do not in fragment1, it would thrown the error like yours. Please check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/Xzaz44I I have uploaded the sample code on GitHub. You could download for reference. https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/Navigation_Drawer  I use you code and xml in `fragment_planet` layout and `NavigationDrawerActivity`.